Route internal subnet between openstack instance
Context:
I have an openstack where 2 instances are connected to a network (subnet 172.26.20.0/24). This network is connected to a virtual router (gateway 172.26.20.1).
Instance 1 ip is 172.26.20.10, and the other 172.26.20.20
Inside these two instances, I have another interface in another private subnet (these interfaces are not linked to an openstack network), respectively 10.0.0.1/24 and 10.0.1.1/24
What I try to achieve :
I would like to be able to ping 10.0.1.1 from instance 1 and ping 10.0.0.1 from instance 2
Quick drawing :
|------------------------|                       |-------------------------|
| VM 1                   |                       | VM 2                    |
| eth0 : 172.26.20.10/24 |     GW : 172.26.20.1  | eth0 : 172.26.20.20/24  |
| veth1 : 10.0.0.1/24    |-->| qrouter | -->     | veth1 : 10.0.1.1/24     |
|------------------------|                       |-------------------------|

VM 1 route :
10.0.1.0/24 via 172.26.20.20

VM 2 route :
10.0.0.1/24 via 172.26.20.10

On both VM net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

ping 172.26.20.10 -> 172.26.20.20 ok
ping 172.26.20.20 -> 172.26.20.10 ok
ping 10.0.0.1 -> 10.0.1.1 ko
ping 10.0.1.1 -> 10.0.0.1 ko

On openstack side : 
Router static route :
10.0.1.0/24 via 172.26.20.20
10.0.0.1/24 via 172.26.20.10

Firewall : All ICMP ingress & egress allowed

I think I'm closed to succeed, but I cannot figure what I missed. Network is not my specialty.
I need this configuration because I have to deploy a kubernetes cluster and I cannot make the network stack working (pod can communicate via 172.26.20.0/24, but not through the internal network 10.0.0.0/16).
Hope it will be clear enough, don't hesitate to ask more precision/clarification
Thanks all.

By default, OpenStack enables "port security" on network ports. This prevents spoofing of IP and MAC addresses. For your configuration to work, you need to explicitly allow the port associated with each of your servers to pass the appropriate ip addresses, or you need to disable port security completely.
I've reproduced your configuration locally; I have:
$ openstack server list -c Name -c Status -c Networks
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Name  | Status | Networks                                   |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| node1 | ACTIVE | default_network=192.168.0.163              |
| node0 | ACTIVE | default_network=192.168.0.8                |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------+

$ openstack router list -c Name -c Status -c State
+----------------+--------+-------+
| Name           | Status | State |
+----------------+--------+-------+
| default_router | ACTIVE | UP    |
+----------------+--------+-------+

On each system, I've configured an additional ip address. On node0:
[root@node0 ~]# ip -4 addr show
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8942 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    altname enp0s3
    altname ens3
    inet 192.168.0.8/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 41999sec preferred_lft 41999sec
3: fake0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global fake0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And on node1:
[root@node1 ~]# ip -4 addr show
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8942 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    altname enp0s3
    altname ens3
    inet 192.168.0.163/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 41979sec preferred_lft 41979sec
3: fake0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.1.1/24 scope global fake0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

We don't need to add any custom routes to either of the servers (because we'll be configuring routes on the router, and the servers are already configured to use that router as a default route). We do need to add custom routes to the router:
$ openstack router add route default_router  \
  --route destination=10.0.0.0/24,gateway=192.168.0.8
$ openstack router add route default_router  \
  --route destination=10.0.1.0/24,gateway=192.168.0.163

In order to get things working, we need to configure the port associated with node0 to pass address 10.0.0.1, and for node1 to pass address 10.0.1.1. We first need to get the port associated with each server:
$ openstack port list --server node0
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                         | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 06d1f9e0-97c0-4c10-a72d-57547cda30b1 |      | fa:16:3e:81:f5:0f | ip_address='192.168.0.8', subnet_id='863b5232-eb01-42fd-85c2-432b61ef3506' | ACTIVE |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+

And then we need to configure the allowed addresses:
$ openstack port set 06d1f9e0-97c0-4c10-a72d-57547cda30b1 \
  --allowed-address ip-address=10.0.0.1

And similarly for node1:
$ openstack port list --server node1
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                           | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 85f2fab7-7479-4178-ab62-fa46764bcf7e |      | fa:16:3e:c4:91:6b | ip_address='192.168.0.163', subnet_id='863b5232-eb01-42fd-85c2-432b61ef3506' | ACTIVE |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
$ openstack port set 85f2fab7-7479-4178-ab62-fa46764bcf7e \
  --allowed-address ip-address=10.0.1.1

With these changes in place, we can reach 10.0.1.1 from node0:
[root@node0 ~]# ping -c1 10.0.1.1
PING 10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.15 ms

--- 10.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.148/1.148/1.148/0.000 ms

And we can reach 10.0.0.1 from node1:
[root@node1 ~]# ping -c 1 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.67 ms

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.671/2.671/2.671/0.000 ms


It is possible to completely disable port security on an individual port or for an entire network. For the situation you've described in your question, neither of these options is necessary, and because they require you to remove all security groups you will need to manage any firewall restrictions inside your individual servers.
To disable port security on a single port:
openstack port set --disable-port-security --no-security-group <port>

To disable port security for an entire network (so that all ports on this network will have port security disabled):
openstack network set --disable-port-security <network>


Thanks for the answer, you made my day. I'll add some informations to your answer for people who want to disable port security
